# accidentally typed sudo shutdown now

Tags: linux

I needed to shutdown the server running Linux but accidentally run the command `sudo shutdown now`. It says it went to single user mode. How can I return it back to its original state?

Comment: Have you tried pushing the power button?

Comment: @seth What is that supposed to do?

Comment: Oh wow I just goofed, That is to bring back to multi-user on my sql server.  for linux i believe "tellinit 3" or "tellinit 5" depending on the run level it was in before you switched to single user mode.  You can also issue a shutdown from that screen. shutdown -r  to reboot

Answer (score 1):

```
initlevel=$(cat /etc/inittab|grep initdefault|cut -d: -f2)
init ${initlevel}
```

Answer (score 1):

To shutdown the server (this works in single use mode or in the normal multiuser mode):

```
shutdown -h now
```

The simple way to get from single user mode back to normal multiuser mode is just to reboot:

```
shutdown -r now
```

You won't need sudo in single user mode because you are root.

---

"[Single user mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-user_mode)" is effectively a maintenance mode. If you want to know more about this, including how to get back to multiuser mode without rebooting, have a look at the [runlevel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runlevel) documentation specific to your version of Linux (i.e. [Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpstartHowto), [Redhat])[4](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/3/html/Reference_Guide/s1-boot-init-shutdown-sysv.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a debian based system (e.g. Debian, Ubuntu, Mint), you can install the **molly-guard** package to help prevent accidental shutdowns.

For most linux systems if you are on the console (i.e. physical keyboard and monitor), you can type

```
init 5
```

to bring the system back up to multi-user state.

Comment: The mistake here wasn't shutting down the wrong computer, it was omitting the `-h` or `-r` option.